# Split a string to dataframe (Col name and value) in R

Tags: r, string, dataframe, replace, split

I am trying to split some data (string) and put them in a data frame. in my string, the first one is the col name and the second part is its value. My data is like this:

```
 "\"id\":247,\"hseStr\":[1,1,1,1],\"pertun\":96,\"sqrMtr\":[2500,2500,2500,2500,2500,2500],\"hDWInt\":[],\"hDWIIncptn\":[],\"hDWIID\"":[],\"cntRateRgn\":\"2102B02\",\"prclID\":\"4748403C\", \"hAction\":null ,\"mAction\":null,\"addrGrps\":null,\"hseEQDdctbl\":[51.8594958810969,42.
```

Ideally, I want to become something like this:

```
id      hseStr    pertun  sqrMtr ...

247   [1,1,1,1]     96     [2500,2500,2500,2500,2500,2500]...
```

Previously, I split the data by "," and then put it in the table, but here because there are more "," that are used in the values such as  [1,1,1,1], I cannot use this method!

I have somehow distinguish between "," that are used in my text and replace them with a different character.

**Update**
Complete string:

```
"{\"id\":21247,\"hs111\":[1,1,1,1],\"p2n\":96,\"sq211\":[20,500,20,20,20,20],\"hoi\":[],\"hsa\":[],\"h961\":[],\"h885\":[],\"t252\":[],\"cn01\":[],\"cD56\":[],\"cI65\":[],\"mD24\":[],\"mD23\":[],\"m63\":[],\"m985\":[],\"h23\":[],\"c112\":[],\"m41\":[],\"r54\":1,\"m63\":\"S6\",\"hs74\":\"2\",\"c55\":\"21\",\"p12\":\"4C\",\"h11\":null,\"m14\":null,\"a12\":null,\"h88\":[1.8,2.3,6.4,28.2,17.9,11.0,7.0,4.1,2.5,0],\"h87\":[3.9,6.1,6.9,4.2,3.7,2.487,1.6],\"cn98\":[1.25,3.1,1.4,12.1,5.3,2.2,1.1,0.5,0.2,0],\"h76\":null,\"c12\":null,\"m54\":null}"
```

Comment: Your data looks very much like json, but if so then it is broken, notice after `\"hDWIID\"` your R-string ends with a d-quote but the string does not stop. Also, your sample data ends abruptly without completing. If this is all of your data, then you're in trouble, as it is not consistent with its own formatting. If there is more, then please provide all of it. Regardless, if it is correct, then you can get a named list with `jsonlite::fromJSON(paste0("{", thisstring, "}"))`. From there, though, you might have issues, as this is not a "normal" json-encoded frame.

Comment: @r2evans Yeap, You are right. I just copied a small part of it.
I provided complete data. Well I don't know that is from Json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can take help from packages built to deal with JSON :

```
stack(jsonlite::fromJSON(string))


#   values   ind
#1   21247    id
#2       1 hs111
#3       1 hs111
#4       1 hs111
#5       1 hs111
#6      96   p2n
#7      20 sq211
#8     500 sq211
#9      20 sq211
#10     20 sq211
#11     20 sq211
#12     20 sq211
#13      1   r54
#14     S6   m63
#15      2  hs74
#16     21   c55
#17     4C   p12
#18    1.8   h88
#19    2.3   h88
#20    6.4   h88
#...
#...
```

This will remove `NULL` values from the output, you can replace it with `NA` if you want to keep it. Also this gives individual rows for every element.

If you want to keep each key as single row and values as list, we can use `enframe` from `tibble`.

```
tibble::enframe(jsonlite::fromJSON(string))


# A tibble: 33 x 2
#   name  value     
#   <chr> <list>    
# 1 id    <int [1]> 
# 2 hs111 <int [4]> 
# 3 p2n   <int [1]> 
# 4 sq211 <int [6]> 
# 5 hoi   <list [0]>
# 6 hsa   <list [0]>
# 7 h961  <list [0]>
# 8 h885  <list [0]>
# 9 t252  <list [0]>
#10 cn01  <list [0]>
# … with 23 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

You can separate the string with `tidyverse` using `separate_rows()` and `separate()`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
string <- "{\"id\":21247,\"hs111\":[1,1,1,1],\"p2n\":96,\"sq211\":[20,500,20,20,20,20],\"hoi\":[],\"hsa\":[],\"h961\":[],\"h885\":[],\"t252\":[],\"cn01\":[],\"cD56\":[],\"cI65\":[],\"mD24\":[],\"mD23\":[],\"m63\":[],\"m985\":[],\"h23\":[],\"c112\":[],\"m41\":[],\"r54\":1,\"m63\":\"S6\",\"hs74\":\"2\",\"c55\":\"21\",\"p12\":\"4C\",\"h11\":null,\"m14\":null,\"a12\":null,\"h88\":[1.8,2.3,6.4,28.2,17.9,11.0,7.0,4.1,2.5,0],\"h87\":[3.9,6.1,6.9,4.2,3.7,2.487,1.6],\"cn98\":[1.25,3.1,1.4,12.1,5.3,2.2,1.1,0.5,0.2,0],\"h76\":null,\"c12\":null,\"m54\":null}"

as.data.frame(string) %>% separate_rows(string, string, sep = ",\"") %>% 
  separate(string, into = c("category","value"), sep = "\":")
#>    category                                      value
#> 1      {"id                                      21247
#> 2     hs111                                  [1,1,1,1]
#> 3       p2n                                         96
#> 4     sq211                       [20,500,20,20,20,20]
#> 5       hoi                                         []
#> 6       hsa                                         []
#> 7      h961                                         []
#> 8      h885                                         []
#> 9      t252                                         []
#> 10     cn01                                         []
#> 11     cD56                                         []
#> 12     cI65                                         []
#> 13     mD24                                         []
#> 14     mD23                                         []
#> 15      m63                                         []
#> 16     m985                                         []
#> 17      h23                                         []
#> 18     c112                                         []
#> 19      m41                                         []
#> 20      r54                                          1
#> 21      m63                                       "S6"
#> 22     hs74                                        "2"
#> 23      c55                                       "21"
#> 24      p12                                       "4C"
#> 25      h11                                       null
#> 26      m14                                       null
#> 27      a12                                       null
#> 28      h88 [1.8,2.3,6.4,28.2,17.9,11.0,7.0,4.1,2.5,0]
#> 29      h87            [3.9,6.1,6.9,4.2,3.7,2.487,1.6]
#> 30     cn98  [1.25,3.1,1.4,12.1,5.3,2.2,1.1,0.5,0.2,0]
#> 31      h76                                       null
#> 32      c12                                       null
#> 33      m54                                      null}
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>